# Check if user is EST timezone and within a set EST time range using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, timezone

I have a situation where I'm trying alert users that are **not** in an EST timezone that try to submit a post between the hours 12am EST to 3am EST.

**pseudo code:**

```
var systemTimeZone = get current EST time ??
var currentUserTime = new Date();

If(currentUserTime > 12am EST && < 3am EST){
  // show alert modal
}
```

How would I go about achieving this an also taking daylight savings into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
// get the current time in the user's local time zone
var nowLocal = moment();

// get the current time in the US Eastern time zone
var nowEastern = moment.tz("America/New_York");

// see if the time zone offsets match or not
if (nowLocal.utcOffset() != nowEastern.utcOffset())
{
    // see if it's before 3:00 AM in the Eastern time zone
    if (nowEastern.hour() < 3)  // note: checking hour >= 0 would be redundant
    {
        alert("It's too early in New York!")
    }
}
```

Comment: What does eastern hour is less than 3 mean. The check should only be if the user is not in eastern time. Or is that what the less than 3 mean and I'm not seeing something that's possibly simple :)

Comment: Updated the answer.  It now only checks if the user's time zone offset is currently aligned with the Eastern time zone.  I think this is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: When I test this code changing my Mac's system timezone nowEastern  is showing Mon Feb 23 2015 09:07:59 GMT-0700 (MST). When it should be showing EST time.

Comment: I'm using moment-timezone-2010-2020.js & moment.js

Comment: You're probably looking at moment's `_d` field - that's internal.  Ignore it.  It works in concert with the other properties.  Use one of the other output functions like `.format()`.

Comment: Ah yes I was thanks for that. I also read zone is depreciated to utcOffset. What does utcOffset return?. For example EST time is showing -420. TRying to find out what that value means in time.

Comment: The function was just renamed, and the sign was inverted to align with normal conventions.  So `zone()` would return `420` where `utcOffset()` will return `-420`.  That is, 420 minutes (or 7 hours) *behind* UTC.

Comment: Thank you for not only answering my questions but explaining them so well. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest looking into something like [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). It takes a lot of the work out of doing date\time comparisons and formatting.

Using moment to do what I think you're trying to achieve above would be:

```
var serverTimeUtc = /* Get from server a UTC time */
var momentTime = moment(serverTimeUtc);
if (momentTime.hour() >= 0 && momentTime.hour() < 3) {
    // Server event occurred between 12am and 3am local time
}
```

If you only care about EST regardless of local time, then you'd have to do some timezone conversion, which [moment.tz](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) can help with.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will provide the Time Zone Offset of the current date, according to Greenwich Mean Time:

```
var today = Date.now();
today = new Date(today);
var systemTimeZone = today.getTimezoneOffset();
```

You just need to calculate the range of Time Zone Offsets for EST: [Timezone Table](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/timezone.htm)

Comment: This would only work out what the users system time zone would be ? The question was also how to return a EST time between 12am & 3am regardless of the users system time zone so it could be checked against a non EST users time. Also how would this work for daylight savings

Answer (score 0):

This library gives you the name of the timezone the user is in. If it does not return "America/New York", you will know the user is NOT in Eastern Time.

http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Comment: Great so that's half the answer. Now how would I go about finding out the check between 12am & 3am EST time is user is not in EST time zone. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, if you want to address your situation to users all over the world and also considering DST's from all over the world (which complicates matters - for instance, parts of Arizona do not observe DST!), I assume that your server is in the EST timezone, so I would make an AJAX call to the server and ask for the server time. Server time would be EST and then you would know directly if it is between 12am and 3am EST. Otherwise, I do not know how to consider all the possible variables in play using only JS. As you can see by my low reputation, I am not a pro coder but that is what I would do